# Why the words used in devise are not always translated...?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, yaml

in devise/sessions/new.html.erb I have this

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :from, @from %>
<!-- Username -->
<div>
    <div><%= f.label :username_or_email %></div>
    <%= f.text_field :username_or_email, autofocus: true, required: true %>
</div>

<!-- Password -->
<div>
    <div><%= f.label :password %></div>
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", required: true %>
</div>
```

But I have a problem with the translation. I don't know why but "password" word sometimes is translated (for example in Japanese) **but** sometimes not (for example in Chinese).

(The word "password" is not added in my config/locales/ja.yml even in config/locales/zh.yml)

While username_or_email is never translated. Why?
Should I download [those files](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/I18n)? Now it works also without them for several words (i don't know how...)

Comment: Could it be that you use https://github.com/tigrish/devise-i18n? And could it be that you use the wrong locale for e.g. China, you would need to use `zh-CN` or `zh-HK`, only `zh` would not work.